# Contractor claims new pantry location is structural - is he right?

Tags: walls, framing, structural, construction

My contractor added the pantry in the middle of the living room instead of its original place to open the space but I didn't like it, then he says it is good for support. The pantry was supposed to be in the red circle but he moved it to the green dot as shown in the attached picture.

I reached the framing inspector of Nashville, TN codes department who gave the approval for the framing inspection and he told me it is not load bearing and it can be removed and already the home plans was approved without it. The only reason I guess that he put the pantry here is to cover the duct work because 2 of the ducts run under the beam but he is trying to convince me that it is important for support. I just need to get another advice to get peace of mind. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What did the plans say… the ones you approved & signed off? That's where it goes. Otherwise, it's just plain & simply "wrong" & needs fixing. Don't even bother arguing. Money stops until build is as specified in the drawings.

Comment: I already contacted the inspector, what is the problem to ask here also

Comment: The plans i attached are the ones approved

Comment: May I suggest replacing your drawings with redacted ones? If it was me, I would omit the address of the new home at least.

Comment: @AldusBumblebore Good catch - I did so

Comment: Did the contractor give any other reasons why he thinks it's a load bearing pantry? It appears to be directly below a main support beam - does he think that beam is too weak or something? Or have you recently decided to add something very heavy upstairs, grand pianos, pool tables and waterbeds in every room?

Comment: You could ask a structural engineer to take a quick look at the plans to sanity-check this. Probably wouldn't be expensive since they wouldn't be doing a site visit. Assuming it _can_ be answered from the plans. (In theory, theory is equivalent to practice, but in practice...)

Comment: Looks to me like the 9' wall is also in the wrong place. Did they just get confused and build the pantry on the wrong side of the kitchen?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't see where the pantry in its existing location is contributing to any support but can see the contractor's concern about the ductwork. How could he just move the pantry without getting any OKs from the owners?  If this is something you're not happy with, get the contractor to move it or it will bug you forever. That's not the way to live in a custom home.

Comment: I don't see any posts under that beam over the fairly long span in the photo. The pantry may well act as a post. However, I can't find details of that in the drawings.

Comment: @isherwood       That's what I first thought too but the laundry room is framed pretty heavy and appears to be supporting the beam so the pantry looks reduntant as far as support.

Answer (score 0):

In order for it to be a load bearing element, there must be an equally strong load bearing element beneath the floor. Is there one in either location? Frankly, I can see no load bearing element in the picture to speak of.

Comment: It's a concrete slab...the whole floor is a load bearing element.

Comment: @Huesmann, that's 100% false. **Any load-bearing post or wall must have a footing under the slab** (or an integrated footing). A 4" slab cannot bear load. Basement or foundation drawings will show this.